# SimpleXML xpath has empty element

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I am currently building a PHP script which will take a Salesforce webhook POST, and am currently struggling to properly parse the Soap XML string and get it into a usable state.

The XML string I am working with is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <notifications
            xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
            <OrganizationId>00DN0000000XXXXXXX</OrganizationId>
            <ActionId>04kN0000000XXXXXXX</ActionId>
            <SessionId xsi:nil="true"/>
            <EnterpriseUrl>https://cs6.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/38.0/00DN0000000XXXXXXX</EnterpriseUrl>
            <PartnerUrl>https://cs6.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/38.0/00DN0000000XXXXXXX</PartnerUrl>
            <Notification>
                <Id>00DN0000000XXXXXXX</Id>
                <sObject xsi:type="sf:Account"
                    xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
                    <sf:Id>00DN0000000XXXXXXX</sf:Id>
                    <sf:FirstName>Bill</sf:FirstName>
                    <sf:LastName>Jack</sf:LastName>
                    <sf:PersonEmail>abc@xyz.net</sf:PersonEmail>
                    <sf:PersonMobilePhone>0400000000</sf:PersonMobilePhone>
                </sObject>
            </Notification>
        </notifications>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The code I am using to pull data out is as follows:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);

$xml->registerXPathNamespace('soapenv', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ob', 'http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('sf', 'urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com');

$notifications = $xml->xpath('//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ob:notifications/ob:Notification/*');
```

I can get as far as getting the children of the `Notification` tag, but no matter what I do, I cannot pull out the `sObject` child and it's relevant data out.

I have tried fiddling with the namespaces, which is where I suspect I have gone wrong, other things I have tried involve using wildcard and other XPath operators to no avail.

What am I doing wrong that means I can't get the sObject via the `xpath()` method?

Comment: In the example you show, what *do* you get out? You say you can get "the children of the Notification tag", but in your example it only has two children, so do you mean you get only 1 result, the `Id` tag but not the `sObject` tag? Or do you get 2 results in the `$notifications` array but don't know how to manipulate them?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear - I get both the Id and sObject, however, only Id has data in it, and sObject comes back empty.

Comment: Aha, now we're getting somewhere. How are you examining it? `var_dump` and `print_r` can't always "see" what's in a SimpleXML object, particularly when namespaces are involved. Try `$foo->asXML()` or https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug and you'll probably see it is there. Then use [the namespace argument to `$foo->children()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) to access the child elements.

Comment: Awesome, using that bit of advice I finally got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've figured out what was happening, and leaving this here in the hopes that anyone who stumbles across the same issue will find this answer helpful. Thanks to IMSoP for helping me get to the answer.

First, SimpleXML's `xpath()` method returns an array, not a XML object, which makes life difficult from the outset. Second of all, if you look at the `<notifications>` tag, you will see it uses the `outbound` namespace, which in my example I aliased to `ob`. As such, both `Notification` and `sObject` are also considered to be part of the same namespace as they are children of the namespaced element, which means the correct xpath is

```
//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ob:notifications/ob:Notification/ob:sObject
```

Which, as mentioned above, in SimpleXML will return an array, so grab the first index, and use the provided namespace url for sObject in the `children()` method call and you will get your data.

So using the above example XML

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <notifications
            xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
            <OrganizationId>00DN0000000XXXXXXX</OrganizationId>
            <ActionId>04kN0000000XXXXXXX</ActionId>
            <SessionId xsi:nil="true"/>
            <EnterpriseUrl>https://cs6.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/38.0/00DN0000000XXXXXXX</EnterpriseUrl>
            <PartnerUrl>https://cs6.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/38.0/00DN0000000XXXXXXX</PartnerUrl>
            <Notification>
                <Id>00DN0000000XXXXXXX</Id>
                <sObject xsi:type="sf:Account"
                    xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
                    <sf:Id>00DN0000000XXXXXXX</sf:Id>
                    <sf:FirstName>Bill</sf:FirstName>
                    <sf:LastName>Jack</sf:LastName>
                    <sf:PersonEmail>abc@xyz.net</sf:PersonEmail>
                    <sf:PersonMobilePhone>0400000000</sf:PersonMobilePhone>
                </sObject>
            </Notification>
        </notifications>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

We can get the data by doing the following:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);

$xml->registerXPathNamespace('soapenv', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ob', 'http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound');

$sObject = $xml->xpath('//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ob:notifications/ob:Notification/ob:sObject')[0];

$data = $sObject->children('urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com');
var_dump($data);
```